# JQuery Autocomplete: make ajax call to collect more details of the selected item from autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I am trying to do is once a user selects a result from the autocomplete, an ajax call is made to a php file to collect more details about the selected item and then the details coming within response are displayed in a textarea box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bookSearch").autocomplete({
        source: "getBooks.php",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: "getBooks2.php"
            })
            .done(function(event, ui){
                $('#bookResults').val(ui.item.value + "\n");
            })
        }
    });
});
```

This is my javascript at the moment. I get an error

> "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" in reference to "$('#bookResults').val(ui.item.value + "\n");".

How can I implement the ajax call into the autocomplete function?

```
<div id="autoComplete">
    <h2 id="searchTitle">Book search</h2>
    <input type="text" id="bookSearch" placeholder="Type in a book name"/>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="bookResults" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the html for `#bookResults`?

Comment: I've added the HTML

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering I have managed to find a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bookSearch").autocomplete({
        source: "getBooks.php",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "get",
                url: "getBooks2.php",
                data: {bookTitle: ui.item.value}
            })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $('#bookResults').val(data);
                })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acccording to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), callback function (`done()`) has only one parameter - data. According to this,

```
.done(function(event, ui) {
```

should be replaced with

```
.done(function(ui) {
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still gives the same error in Chrome debugger

Comment: and what if just below done you add `console.log(ui)`? what does the console log? Because that basically means than on the object `ui` is no property named `item`. `item` is undefined, so js tries to get property `value` from `undefined`.